# Optimum memory management for NSMutableArrays

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsmutablearray

A quick question that I really need answered:

Which uses more memory?

A `NSMutableArray` with a *million objects* **OR** a million `NSMutableArrays` with one object?

Will there even be a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A million NSMutableArrays with one object would consume more memory.

Suppose a basic NSMutableArray implementation which has a pointer and a size for its elements:

- the pointer would be 4 to 8 bytes
- the size would be 4 to 8 bytes
- then each instance would require two allocations (one for the object, one for the array), which means those addresses are tracked someplace.
- add a pointer for `isa`, another 4 to 8 bytes

Now this is not necessarily exactly how NSMutableArray is implemented, but it gives you an idea of memory cost for each instance in a general purpose implementation.

So would you rather take the sum of all those parts and:

- add 1000000 * `sizeof(int*)`
- or multiply it by 1000000?

That should give you an idea that 1M arrays will consume much more memory. Of course, you can test this using Instruments if you need real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for this. I realised how I could create 1 million arrays within an array easily and have done some tests. As I do not have 10 reputation I cant post my own answer and the code I used. Here are the results anyway:One million objects in one array: peak = 26.4MB, steady = 11MB, time: 2.052 seconds.

One million arrays with one object: peak = 98.2MB, steady = 11.6 MB, time: 2.614 seconds. I find this quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

A million arrays would use much more memory.